# React not loading mysql data - SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here.  I'm trying to pull data from a mysql database and display it on a react page.

Here's the query:

```
static getTopPost(){
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      pool.query(
         'SELECT * FROM blog_post ORDER BY create_date LIMIT 1',
         function (error, results, fields) {
            if(error) return reject(error);
               resolve(results);
         }
      )
   })
}
```

Here's the get

```
router.get('/top', (req, res) => {
    const post = req.app.locals.engine.generation.topPost();
    PostTable.getTopPost(post)
        .then(post => console.log(post))
        .catch(error => console.error('error', error));
    res.end();
})
```

Here's the react:

```
fetchPost = () => {
   fetch('http://localhost:3000/post/top')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
         this.setState({ post: json.post})
      })
      .catch(error => console.error('error', error));
}
```

In terminal I see the data(referenced in screenshot):

[Screen grab from terminal in IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGsxi.png)

However it doesn't appear when I load the page.  When I check the console in Firefox I get the following message:

error SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Let me know if more info is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res.end()` means you are returning empty 200 status response. try to `res.json()` for json response and pass your post details inside parenthesis.

Comment: After re-reading, those last 6 words mattered the most.  Thanks for the help